# How to iterate on a row returned in PHP sql and store each value in a different variable

Tags: php

I have a fuction that returns a row of values as below

```
 fldClientID    fldPetID    fldName    fldBreed             fldType   fldInactive
> 1406          114        Lola         Poodle - Toy          Dog           0 
  1406          5786       Izadora      Chihuahua long hair   Dog           0 
  1406          8728       Kurmo        Maltese Mix           Dog           0
```

The pet id is different on each pet but same client id I need a method to iterate through the return resurtset and store each pet in a variable like

```
PETNAME1= lola      PETBREED1= Poodle-To
PETNAME2= Izadora   PETBREED2 =chihuahua long hair
```

I have tried this code but stores only the first pet all way through

```
  $pets=$this->readPet();

   While(next($pets))
     {
         $petname1=$pets['fldName'];
         $petbreed1=$pets['fldBreed'];

        $petname2=$pets['fldName'];
        $petbreed2=$pets['fldBreed'];
     }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can simply use the resulted array to access those values

Comment: @MateiMihai please explain how to achieve that from the resulted array

Comment: The returned result set you just wrote about would be an array with keys and values. Keys would be the columns names

Comment: @MateiMihai can you do a sample code for that

Answer (score 0):

You could show what you have tried already. Some code whould be nice.
Anyway, something like:

```
$pets = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $pets[$row->fldName] = $row->fldBreed;
}
```

EDIT: if you want an array with keys as pet names and values as breeds.

EDIT #2: With dynamic variable assignment. This is for educational purposes only. This is a very bad way to work with data iterations.

```
$counter = 0;
while($counter < count($pets)){
    ${'petname' . ($counter+1)} = $pets[$counter]['fldName'];
    ${'petbreed' . ($counter+1)} = $pets[$counter]['fldBreed'];
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}

echo $petname1;
echo ' - ' . $petbreed1;
echo "<br>";
echo $petname2;
echo ' - ' . $petbreed2;
```

A better solution would be using something like [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to modify your array.

```
$pets = array_column($arr, 'fldBreed', 'fldName');
var_dump($pets);
```

Comment: Explain more on this

Comment: Surely there animals with the same name... This could would overwrite existing date, leading to incorrect results

Comment: Check my edits. In the second edit you can access the breeds with $pets[petname], eg. $pets['Lola'], to get the breed